# ASP.NET Core 2.1 XmlNodeReader

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1

Reading Outer Xml on a XmlNode with the XmlNodeReader returns an empty string in ASP.NET Core 2.1.

```
private string ReadXml(XmlNode element)
{
    using (var reader = new XmlNodeReader(element))
    {
        return reader.ReadOuterXml();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use the ReadOuterXml method?

Comment: Do you have a *complete* example that shows this? For example: what is `XmlNode` here? the name `element` suggests that it is an element (`XmlElement`) - but: we don't know that.

Comment: You are right is actually a XmlElement in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a test here, invoking `MoveToContent()` seems to make it work:

```
static void Main()
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(@"<foo><bar abc=""def"">ghi</bar></foo>");
    var el = doc.SelectSingleNode("/foo/bar");
    var s = ReadXml(el);
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
private static string ReadXml(XmlNode element)
{
    using (var reader = new XmlNodeReader(element))
    {
        reader.MoveToContent();
        return reader.ReadOuterXml();
    }
}
```

The reader starts *before* the first node, basically (the `reader.NodeType` is `None` before you move to the content).

---

It may also be simpler to use:

```
return element.OuterXml;
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test.